# Installing GDAL extensions in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, gdal

I'm trying to get GDAL extensions to work in a Geoserver standalone installation. I'm following these instructions:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html

Upon starting Geoserver, I can see that GDAL has been installed. It doesn't seem to work properly though:

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and `gdal-bin` and `libgdal-java` are installed. How can I fix this?

For the sake of completion, here is the error message in text form:

```
JNI GDAL Wrapper Version: unavailable
```

Comment: Those instructions are valid for GeoServer 2.16.x onwards, what version of GeoServer are you using?

Comment: @AndreaAime I'm using 2.15.2. Can you direct me to the proper instructions? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the stable series of GeoServer (currently 2.15.x) you can use these instructions:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html

The properly tested packages are the ones of the custom GDAL 1.9.2 build, there are hints on how to use a different/newer version too, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I've tried to follow these instructions before, but I'm not able to install the native libraries since they're only offered up to Ubuntu 12. Do I have to compile GDAL myself for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: That's odd, I am on a recent Linux Mint and a few months ago the old libs were still working. Are you sure you don't have the newer GDAL libraries in the path, before the ones that GeoServer should be running with?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I eventually figured out what's wrong: I was starting Geoserver with a systemd unit and since that forks its own process, it was ignoring my environment variables. Now, everything is up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I want to post some additional info for people who might run into problems installing the GDAL extensions on Ubuntu 16.04, following the instructions on https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html

These are my observations:

- In my case, setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable was not needed.
- The gdal data (http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.15.2/extensions/geoserver-2.15.2-gdal-plugin.zip) needs to be installed to `geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib`
- The native libraries (https://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/native/gdal/1.9.2/linux/gdal192-Ubuntu12-gcc4.6.3-x86_64.tar.gz) need to be installed and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable needs to point to the directory in which the tar.gz is unpacked.
- If you're using systemd to start geoserver via geoserver-(version)\bin\startup.sh, you need to define your environment variables in the systemd unit since it spawns its own subprocess.